# Combobox doesn't show the list at first click in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, combobox

We're using a jquery.each to calculate the content of the combobox. On firefox and chrome, the first click does calculate this and show up the list. However, on IE, the first click calculate, but doesn't show up. You can see the values are there by scrolling down though. The second click is fine, and you can see everything.

The following code is called from a button's focus.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    data:{
        'longueurA' : longueurA,
        'longueurB' : longueurB,
        'longueur1' : longueur1LI,
        'longueur2' : longueur2LI,
        'name'      : 'ILOT'
    },
    success: function(results){
        if(results != ''){
            var options='';
            options+='<option value="'+largeurminIlot+'x'+profondeurminIlot+'">Aucune sélection...</option>';
            jQuery.each(results, function(){
                options+='<option value="'+this.largeur+'x'+this.profondeur+'">'+this.largeur+'x'+this.profondeur+'</option>';
            });
            jQuery("#"+name).html(options)
        }
        else{
            var options='';
            options+='<option value="">Aucun résultat</option>';
            jQuery("#"+name).html(options)
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        var options='';
        options+='<option value="">Aucun résultat</option>';
        jQuery("#"+name).html(options)
    }
});
```

Comment: You're going to have to post some code I'm afraid, no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Here you go.

Comment: Thats fine. When you say the first click, do you mean the initial option value? ie: options+='<option value="'+largeurminIlot+'x'+profondeurminIlot+'">Aucune sélection...</option>';

Comment: I mean, the first time I click on the combo box, I can't see all the results. I have to click a second time. Here is a screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/iaIaJ72.png

Comment: Found ! The code above wass called by a .focus(...), and to fix you just have to use .focusin :) Thank you for your time Stumblor

Comment: Are you sure the ajax POST has returned by the time you execute your first click? Works fine for me when testing with dummy data: http://jsfiddle.net/ENcC2/3/

Comment: No problem, have a look at my answer below and mark it as solved if you're happy, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bérenger mentioned, the code to populate the dropdown was being called on focus. A better option would be to populate the dropdown on document ready.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    // code to retrieve values
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        ...
    });
});
```

Additionally, the `async` value should be set to `true` to ensure that code execution is not halted while the dropdown is populating. To ensure that the user is not confused by an empty dropdown, you could hide it until the values are populated.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    jQuery("#"+name).hide();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        ...
        success: function(data) {
           // build options string
           // ...
           $("#"+name).html(options).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```